# If $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\ \mathrm dx=100$ then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(100x+9)\ \mathrm dx =?$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

> Given $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\ dx=100$, evaluate $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(100x+9)\ dx.$

Question is as above. I'm not sure how to even start. Is the answer $100$? Seems like if the function is bounded from negative infinity to infinity, any transformation just changes the shape. Not sure how to explain this properly though.

Comment: $\large z \equiv 100x + 9$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting $u=100x+9$ we have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(100x+9)\,dx=\frac{1}{100}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u)\,du=\frac{100}{100}=1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider a particular example.  What if $f(x) = 1$ for $0 < x < 100$ and $f(x) = 0$ elsewhere?  What is $f(100x+9)$ in this case?  What is the value of the second integral?

Comment: $f(100x+9)$ = $0$ for $9 < x < 909$ and $f(100x+9)$ = $1$ for everywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

We know that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx=\lim_{x\to \infty}(F(x)-F(-x))=100\tag 1$$

Considering $dF(ax+b)\over dx$ we get $af(ax+b)$, so we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ax+b)dx=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{F(ax+b)-F(-ax+b)}a=\frac {100}a\tag 2$$

With $a=100$ we get $1$ as the value of the right-hand side of $(2)$.

Comment: That's not correct!

Comment: Dang, typing faster than I was thinking...

Comment: I should quit answering questions outside the realm of finite differences...

Comment: It happens to all of us.